# PDO - order by price ascending or descending

Tags: php, mysql, search, pdo, sql-order-by

currently I have a simple search query which works as follows:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$chosencategory = $_GET['category'];
$price = $_GET['price'];

$search = $_GET['search'];
$terms = explode(" ", $search);

if ($price && $chosencategory){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE MATCH (lname,fname) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND category='$chosencategory' ORDER BY price $price";
    $q   = $conn->prepare($sql) or die("failed!");
    $q->bindValue(':search',"%".$search."%",PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->execute();
    }
```

When a user chooses, for example, "display price lowest to highest" the value sent through to `$_GET['price']` = ASC, however i am not sure if this is a safe way to sort the results, does anyone have a better way?

also this method is not the best as when the user choses a sort option such as "display price lowest to highest" the dropdown box echoes the value which has been sent to the $_GET['price'] which is "ASC" so in the dropdown box it reads ASC after the form as been sent!

Sorry if this is confusing please comment if you would like me to re-explain this, any help or advice is much appreciated!!

Comment: There are only two values for order by in this case, do why not hard code them in? `<option value="ASC" <?php if($_GET["price"] == "ASC") { echo " selected='selected'"; } ?>>Low to high</option>` or something along those lines. Youcoulduse an array and loop to do the same thing as well.

Comment: why are you not preparing all your values or at least checking there ASC/DESC? ect

Comment: What you are doing is **not secure** and you **will be hacked** if you haven't already!  Bind all values.  You're already 90% of the way there.

Comment: thankyou for your feedback! how would i bind the rest of the values?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone could you please explain how i would prepare/check my values, i am very new at this and trying to teach myself! would appreciate further explanation on how to do this, thankyou very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related to your value binding and sql injection, you should also check that values are set before using. if you enabled `error_reporting(E_ALL)` you would see lots of Undefined warnings. Here are some tips/changes:

```
<?php 
// Check and set username
$username = (isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : 'guest');

// Check and set category
$category = (!empty($_GET['category']) ? $_GET['category'] : null);

// Check and set search
if(!empty($_GET['search'])){
    $search = $_GET['search'];
    $terms  = explode(" ", $search);
}else{
    $search = null;
    $terms  = null;
}

// Check that $_GET['price'] is ASC if not set to DESC
// as static values its ok to directly put in the query 
if(isset($_GET['price']) && $_GET['price'] == 'ASC'){
    $price = 'ASC';
}else{
    $price = 'DESC';
}

if ($category !== null && $search !== null){

    $sql = "SELECT   *
            FROM     people
            WHERE    MATCH (lname,fname) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)
            AND      category = :category
            ORDER BY price ".$price;

    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    // Bind the params to the placeholders
    $q->bindParam(':search', $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindParam(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->execute();
    // Get result
    $result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
?>
```

Comment: thankyou so much! this has been so helpful, im trying to learn how to make better queries using PDO but i always get confused with the binding as sometimes it doesnt work! just a quick question, why is it that price is set out like '.$price;' and not ':price' and how comes that value doesnt need to be binded?

Comment: just tested out your code, the search doesn't actually work now, do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: Enable error reporting then check the logs also enable error reporting on the pdo connection `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` and surround it in a try catch exception. Looking at it it should work, it most likely something up with the query.